# php - mysql select last inserted record between two dates (every month)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table: box (id autoincrement, net_amount, created_at timestamp);
I need to create a query in php mysql to select the last inserted record every month. Thus to get the net_amount at the end of every month.
I am trying this simple query:

```
select * from box
 where box.created_at < 20055332516028
```

While the max created_at in my table is  2017-10-14 10:42:30, there is no records when I use the given query, I need to increase the number to get the records!!!

Comment: so you have to get record which are inserted during months last two dates right?

Comment: I need to get the last inserted record within every month. Last record between start and end of every month.

Comment: so you specify the value of start and end? i meam between values right?

Comment: You can't do it by a single query - at least you need list of month, which is not present now in your tane. Make mysql procedure, temporary table  or do it by php and some queries

Comment: Yes, I have made the loop. As flying suggested in his answer, I think I still need to recreate the start and end dates, as flying suggested in his answer.I used         $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2016-01-1"));
and             $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2016-01-1 +" . $i . " month"));
 then $fromTimeStamp = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fromDate));
        $fromTimeStamp = strtotime($fromTimeStamp);
        $toTimeStamp = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($toDate));
        $toTimeStamp = strtotime($toTimeStamp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`20055332516028` is not a Unix timestamp. You need to get timestamp of the end of the previous month, something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'),$date->format('m'),1);
$date->setTime(0,0,0);
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));
$endOfMonth = $date->getTimestamp();
```

and then use it in a query:

```
select * from box where box.created_at < unix_timestamp(?) order by box.created_at desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thank u. I think u r correct, but I still need to specify a starting date, Am I correct?

Comment: I am using a loop with $i to be incremented. and using the following to create the start and end dates in timestamps:                            $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2016-01-1"));
         $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2016-01-1 +" . $i . " month")); 
         $fromTimeStamp = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fromDate));
         $fromTimeStamp = strtotime($fromTimeStamp);
         $toTimeStamp = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($toDate));
         $toTimeStamp = strtotime($toTimeStamp);
pls how to specify the date in your solution?

Comment: It really depends on what is inside your table and what information you're trying to get. If it is "last record inserted at specified month" then it is basically "sort all records by reverse date, filter out ones that are after end of specified month and take first one" and it is what my proposed query is for.

Comment: @GaliloGalilo I've updated my answer by adding use of `unix_timestamp()` function in a query. It is important because dealing with dates correctly should involve timezone definition and your database stores dates as timestamps. Also you may want to bring your dates to same timezone, e.g. `UTC`

Comment: So I think I need a method to begin from a starting date and get the end of month, then the end of the next month and so on till the current date. I think I need to change the requirements!! :( sorry.

Comment: For date specification you need to refer [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object specification. Basically you can use `$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M1D'))` to certainly move date to next month and then tune it to the "last second of the month" like it is shown in my example

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem your looking for this:-

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM box b1 LEFT JOIN box b2
ON (b1.name = b2.name AND b1.id < b2.id)
WHERE b1.created_at < PUT YOUR DATE  and b2.id IS NULL;
```

Hope it helps